# Auto-scroll Cypress behaviour is causing dropdown to close in Cypress test. Is there a workaround?

Tags: cypress

Cypress's auto-scroll behaviour is closing a dropdown that I am trying to select an element in. This leads to the test failing because the first dropdown item cannot be found.

A work around I have added is adding a second `.click()` to reopen the dropdown after typing the input:

```js
    cy.get(selector).click({ force: true });
    cy.get(selector).type(input);
    cy.get(selector).click();
    cy.get(itemSelector).first().click({ force: true });
```

But this seems clunky. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of mitigations to try (all are clunky).

- scroll the element before interacting with it (since you have to force the click)
- turn off scroll-behavior
- make the viewport large enough that scrolling is unnecessary

```js
it('tests without scrolling', {scrollBehavior:false}, () => {
  cy.viewport(1500,1000)
  cy.visit(...)

  cy.get(selector).scrollIntoView()
  cy.get(selector).click()           // should not have to force
  cy.get(selector).type(input)
  cy.get(itemSelector).first().click()
})
```